# Canvas portion of function won't run?

Tags: javascript

```js
changeCanvasBackground = function() {
  document.getElementById("ji").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  document.getElementById("ji").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed two!";
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2D');
  ctx.fillStyle("Red");
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeCanvasBackground);
```

```html
<p id="ji">Hello</p>
<div id="gameArea">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

The 'changeCanvasBackground' function does run, but the canvas portion does not, 'document.getElementById("ji")' is there to show this. If any one can help me out .

Comment: It should read `getContext("2d")`, the capitalization is incorrect. Also you need to call `ctx.fillRect` and give it coordinates, `fillStyle` only tells it what color to use when you execute a fill

Comment: I have added 'fillReact' and changed to '2d' . It is still not working, could there be something else wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `getContext` takes lower case characters `2d`
- You need to call [fillRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) after fillStyle
- `fillStyle` is a property and not a method

So the three lines should look like this:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

The final result will be like so:

```js
changeCanvasBackground = function() {
  document.getElementById("ji").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  document.getElementById("ji").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed two!";
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeCanvasBackground);
```

```html
<p id="ji">Hello</p>
<div id="gameArea">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: `var ctx = canvas.getContext('2D');` will set `ctx` to `null`, needs to be "2d"

Comment: Okay, I have fixed the answer

Comment: I had "ctx.fillStyle("Red");", ok property not method. Thanks